# why can I return a function before it has been declared in javascript?

Tags: javascript

Why does the following work:

```
function outsideFunction() {
   return {
    insideFunction: insideFunction
}

function insideFunction() {
    ...stuff
}
}
```

isn't

```
function insideFunction() {
    ...stuff
}
```

the same as

```
var insideFunction = function() { ...stuff }
```

which would cause `var insideFunction` to be hoisted to the top?
Shouldn't `insideFunction` return `undefined` when used in the object declaration?

Can I do the same thing with an object?
In other words, can I do:

```
return {objectName: objectName}
var objectName = {}
```

Comment: `hoisting` is the answer

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the scope of variables in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/500431/what-is-the-scope-of-variables-in-javascript)

Comment: @Tushar Hoisting is just that js moves all declaration to the top not the initializations. This has to do with the variable scope and that the functions don't use the variables until it's executet later in code...

Comment: @bang `function` declaration *statements* are also hoisted to the top, so that's why binding a function to a local symbol via a `var` initialization is *not* the same as doing so with a function declaration statement.

Comment: @Tushar I addressed hoisting in my original post. Hoisting just moves var insideFunction to the top. However, as I understood it, before the variable is initialized it should resolve to undefined...

Comment: @DavidHaim tried what? I have tried doing this with functions (i.e. using them in an object initialization before declaring them and it works. I have not tried it with objects.

Comment: If the initialisation is not hoisted as well as the declaration then it can still work if the call is not made until after it has been initialised. ie outsideFunction is called later.

Comment: Sorry, to quick... Hoisting is the answer, and also the answer to why the last block of code won't work. It's only the declaration that's moved to the top....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is because of hoisting - things are accessible before you've declared them, as all declaration is "hoisted" to the top of your scope.  You say:

> isn't
>
> ```
> function insideFunction() {
>     ...stuff
> }
> ```
>
> the same as
>
> ```
> var insideFunction = function() { ...stuff }
> ```

No.  As per [the MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/function#Function_declaration_hoisting):

> Function declarations in JavaScript are hoisting the function
>   definition. You can use the function before you declared it:
>
> ```
> hoisted(); // logs "foo"
>
> function hoisted() {
>   console.log("foo");
> }
> ```
>
> Note that function expressions are not hoisted:
>
> ```
> notHoisted(); // TypeError: notHoisted is not a function
>
> var notHoisted = function() {
>    console.log("bar");
> };
> ```

So with your final question:

> can I do:
>
> ```
> return {objectName: objectName}
> var objectName = {}
> ```

Again, no.  Whilst `objectName` will be declared (so you avoid a Reference Error), it's value at the point you return will be `undefined`.

Answer (score -1):

Hoisting is JavaScript's default behavior of moving all declarations to the top of the current scope (**to the top of the current script or the current function**).
And JavaScript initializations are not hoisted. So the answer to your question is no.
For more information go to the follwoing link
[w3schools.com](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_hoisting.asp)